# does within the "range a and b" include a and b?

Tags: co.combinatorics, counting-complexity

I have not found the answer to this doubt of mine elsewhere, hence posting it here. 
It may be a silly question but I just want to be sure :P 
would be great if someone could help me out with this doubt!

Comment: It is generally explicitly mentioned if 'a' or 'b' is included or excluded. Otherwise, the set notation for open interval: (a,b) means neither 'a' nor 'b' is included. On the other hand [a,b) means 'a' is included and 'b' is not included. Likewise, you can use '[' or ')' accordingly.

Comment: @Inuyashayagami I see. but incase no brackets are given and nothing 'inclusive' or 'exclusive' given ?

Answer (score 0):

If your talking about programming, most languages default to include and and not b unless explicitly corrected. If your talking about a math or computer science problem, the problem must state explicitly if it's included or not. If it is  not mentioned, it's basically a 50/50, though I'm pretty sure it's generally accepted that if it is not mentioned. you can default to "inclusive".